# Conditional to check if a field exists for a channel

Tags: conditionals

Is there a way to check if a field with a certain short name exists for a given channel? I'm not checking if a field is left blank, but if it even exists in the field group.

Currently, this only checks for it being blank, but not if it exists. I'm sharing a template for a few channels, but certain fields aren't mirror images of each other per-channel.

```
{if {segment_1}_code}{{segment_1}_code}{/if}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, no. The template parser doesn't know whether fields exist or not.

What would you do differently based on a field being empty vs. a field not existing? Don't they end up with the same result (conditional fails)?

Comment: It's not really to do anything differently, but the project strayed in a different direction. Many channels basically have the same layouts and fields, but instead of reworking the fields (since the client already populated a lot of content), I would rather just keep the work minimal on the template side and ignore fields that don't exist, but output their content if they do exist and have content.

Comment: Right - but I'm wondering how your template code would change in either case? What would you do differently in your syntax if you were checking `if exists and not empty` vs. simply `if not empty`?